# Error: Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s using FlatList (React Native)

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, infinite-scroll

I'm implementing Infinite Scroll with Cloud Firestore and using the lastVisible as the document reference to know where to being the refreshing queries for another 5 users (limit is set to 5).

I have the keyExtractor using the item.id, but still returning the error **Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.%s%s** even though I'm using item.id for the keyExtractor.

```
keyExtractor={(item) => {
  item.id;
}}
```

I've also tried using item.id.toString() from a post on stackoverflow, but that didn't work either.

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, Dimensions, FlatList, View, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import firebaseConfig from '../config/config';

// Imports: Components
import UserSelector from '../components/UserSelector';
import TitleLarge from '../components/TitleLarge';

// Screen Dimensions
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

// Screen: Flat List (Users)
class FlatListUsers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      limit: 5,
      lastVisible: null,
      loading: false,
      refreshing: false,
    };
  }

  // Component Will Mount
  componentWillMount = () => {
    // Firebase: Initialize
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: `${firebaseConfig.apiKey}`,
      authDomain: `${firebaseConfig.authDomain}`,
      databaseURL: `${firebaseConfig.databaseURL}`,
      projectId: `${firebaseConfig.projectId}`,
      storageBucket: `${firebaseConfig.storageBucket}`,
      messagingSenderId: `${firebaseConfig.messagingSenderId}`,
    });
  }

  // Component Did Mount
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.retrieveUsers();
  }

  // Retrieve Users
  retrieveUsers = async () => {
    try {
      // Set State: Loading
      this.setState({ loading: true });

      // Firebase: Database + Settings
      const db = firebase.firestore();

      // Query
      console.log('Fetching Users')
      const initialQuery = await db.collection('users')
                        .where('company', '==', 'Google')
                        .orderBy('first_name')
                        .limit(this.state.limit);

      // Query Snapshot
      const querySnapshot = await initialQuery.get();

      // Document Data
      console.log('Document Data');
      const documentData = querySnapshot.docs.map(document => document.data());
      console.log(documentData);

      // Last Visible Document
      let lastVisible = documentData[documentData.length - 1];

      // Set State
      await this.setState({
        data: documentData,
        lastVisible: lastVisible,
        loading: false,
        refreshing: false,
      });

      console.log('Last Visible');
      console.log(typeof this.state.lastVisible)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.lastVisible))
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Retrieve More Users
  retrieveMore = async () => {
    try {
      const { lastVisible } = this.state;

      console.log('Retrieving more Users (Retrieve More)');
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      await console.log(`Last Visible (Retrieve More): ${this.state.lastVisible}`);

      // Firebase: Database + Settings
      const db = firebase.firestore();

      // Query
      console.log('Paginated Query starting (Retrieve More)');
      const paginatedQuery = await db.collection('licenses')
                        .where('company', '==', 'Google')
                        .orderBy('first_name')
                        .startAfter(lastVisible)
                        .limit(this.state.limit)

      // Query Snapshot
      const querySnapshot = await paginatedQuery.get();
      console.log(`Query Snapshot (Retrieve More): ${querySnapshot}`);

      // Document Data
      const documentData = querySnapshot.docs.map(document => document.data());
      console.log(`Document Data (Retrieve More): ${documentData}`);

      // Last Visible Document (Used As Query Position)
      let lastVisible = documentData[documentData.length - 1];
      console.log(`Last Visible New (Retrieve More): ${lastVisible}`);

      // Set State
      this.setState({
          data: [...this.state.data, ...documentData],
          lastVisible: lastVisible,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false,
      });
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Render Header
  renderHeader = () => {
    try {
      return (
        <TitleLarge title="Users" />
      )
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Render Footer
  renderFooter = () => {
    try {
      // Check If Loading
      if (this.state.loading) {
        return (
          <View style={styles.activityIndicator}>
            <ActivityIndicator />
          </View>
        )
      }
      else {
        return null;
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => ( 
            <UserSelector
              key={(item, index) => {
                return item.id;
              }}
              firstName={item.first_name}
              lastName={item.last_name}
              company={item.company}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => {
            item.id;
          }}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          onEndReached={()=>{
            if (this.state.loading === false) {
             this.retrieveMore();
            }
          }}          
          onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: height,
    width: width,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
  },
  scrollView:{
    height: 'auto',
  },
  UserContainer: {
    width: width,
    marginBottom: 7,
  },
  itemText: {
    fontFamily: 'System',
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: '#222222',
    marginLeft: 16,
  },
  activityIndicator: {
    paddingVertical: 20,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderTopColor: '#CED0CE',
  },
});

// Exports
export default FlatListUsers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add **keyExtractor** into your **FlatList** code:

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
```

Update below code and it will help you.

```
            <FlatList
                            data={this.state.data}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => (
                                <UserSelector
                                    key={(item, index) => {
                                        return item.id;
                                    }}
                                    firstName={item.first_name}
                                    lastName={item.last_name}
                                    company={item.company}
                                />
                            )}
                            keyExtractor={(item) => {
                                item.id;
                            }}
                            ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
                            ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
                            onEndReached={() => {
                                if (this.state.loading === false) {
                                    this.retrieveMore();
                                }
                            }}
                            onEndReachedThreshold={0}
                        />
```

Regarding keyExtractor description:

```
keyExtractor tells the list to use the ids for the react keys instead of the default key property.
```

Comment: Thank you! Replacing the keyExtractor line with the following worked: keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to return in keyExtractor

```
keyExtractor={(item) => {
  return item.id.toString()
}}
```

## OR

```
keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
```